# Putting references on unity button so that I can use a function from another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a Button Prefab that I want to use to increase the health of my player. What I have a problem with is that my gainHealth function is in my Player Script and I tried referencing it in my addListeners. I just want the to Health Button to give my player Health when clicked, the problem is that this button is a prefab.

```
void AddListeners()    
{
    itemButton.onClick.AddListener(() => GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<PlayerHealth>().GainHealth(50));
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.slots.Length; i++)
        {
            if (inventory.isFull[i] == false)
            {
                inventory.isFull[i] = true;
                Instantiate(itemButton, inventory.slots[i].transform, false);
                AddListeners ();
                Destroy(gameObject);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a script on your button prefab, and look something like this.

```
public PlayerHealth P_Health;

void Start()
{
    P_Health = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<PlayerHealth>();
}
//Reference this action as Onclickevent through the Inspector inside your button
void OnMyClick()
{
    P_Health.GainHealth(50);
}
```

Once the button is instantiated it will keep a reference of the PlayerHealth object and call the "GainHealth" function once the button is clicked.

You should put the "OnMyClick()" (or how you like to name it) function in the On Click Event of the button in your prefab editor.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is possible by changing a little thing. Currently your trying to add the listener directly to your prefab. Instead of this you should add the listener to the Button you instantiated with your Prefab.

An example that should work:

```
public GameObject itemButtonPrefab; // drag your Prefab to this field in the inspector
public Button itemButton;  // the "real" instance of your prefab in the scene

void AddListeners()    
{
    itemButton.onClick.AddListener(() => GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<PlayerHealth>().GainHealth(50));
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.slots.Length; i++)
        {
            if (inventory.isFull[i] == false)
            {
                inventory.isFull[i] = true;
                itemButton = Instantiate(itemButtonPrefab, inventory.slots[i].transform, false).GetComponent<Button>();
                AddListeners ();
                Destroy(gameObject);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS: This example should also work an is slightly more performant due to the fact you don't have to call the GetComponent-method:

```
public Button itemButtonPrefab; // drag your Prefab to this field in the inspector
public Button itemButton;  // the "real" instance of your prefab in the scene

void AddListeners()    
{
    itemButton.onClick.AddListener(() => GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<PlayerHealth>().GainHealth(50));
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < inventory.slots.Length; i++)
        {
            if (inventory.isFull[i] == false)
            {
                inventory.isFull[i] = true;
                itemButton = Instantiate(itemButtonPrefab, inventory.slots[i].transform, false);
                AddListeners ();
                Destroy(gameObject);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```